# Ajax.Pro.dll in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

Now, I upgrade my web application from .NET4.0 to 4.5.2.

In my app, I use Ajax.Pro.dll.

In aspx.file, call ajaxMethod like follow by javascript.

```
function callAjax() {
     ajaxClass.ajaxMethod();
}
```

In cs.file there are ajaxMethod like follow.

```
class AjaxClass
{
    [AjaxPro.AjaxMethod]
    public void AjaxMethod()
    {
         this.textBox.text = "AjaxCalled!!";
    }
}
```

In .NET4.0, My app ran completely. But in .NET4.5, ajaxClass is null.
Is Ajax.Pro.dll used in .NET4.5?
Please answer my problem.

Comment: The first snippet isn't C#. Is it malformed Javasctipt? (missing a `;`)? Where is the code that *creates* `ajaxClass? Why do you think that the framework version is responsible for what appears to be a Javascript error?

Comment: Thank, Panagiotis Kanavos. The first snippest is JavaScript in .aspx file. The reason why I think the framework ver. is responsible for this error is in .net4.0, my app ran, but in 4.5,  not run.

Comment: that doesn't mean anything - you may have forgotten to add a Javascript library when upgrading. The important thing is the code that actually creates `ajaxClass`. Obviously, there is an error there. Without it, it's impossible to help